# Adding multiple markers in Gmap3

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, plot, google-maps-markers

I am using Gmap3. I wants to plot multiple markers in map. 
This is my data array for markers :

```
dt.push({
        latLng : [ v.vehicleLat, v.vehicleLng ],
                data : data,
                options : {
                    icon : APP_URL_ROOT + 'img/nits_marker/'+ color + '_32.png'
                }
            });
```

This is my plotting code :

```
$('#' + dMap).gmap3({
    marker : {
        values : data,
        options : {
            draggable : false
        },
        events : {
            click : function(marker, event, context) {
                var map = $(this).gmap3("get");

                if (infoBubble.isOpen()) {
                    infoBubble.close();
                }
                infoBubble.setContent(context.data);
                infoBubble.open(map, marker);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This code works well and plots only the last marker. I could not find the problem. Is there anybody can suggest me what could be the reason behind this problem?

Comment: http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/10-overlays/marker-41

Answer (score 0):

//edit: not with gmap, easier..

You can easely make a function to add markers:

```
function drawMarker(coordinates)
    {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker
        ({
            position: coordinates,
            map: map,
            icon:image,
            title:'any text'
        });
        marker.setMap(map);


      }
```

Does this help you?